# Capitalizing a sentence

Tags: ruby, string, activesupport

Is there a method (perhaps in some library from Rails) or an easy way that capitalizes the first letter of a string without affecting the upper/lower case status of the rest of the string? I want to use it to capitalize error messages. I expect something like this:

```
"hello iPad" #=> "Hello iPad"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a capitalize method in Ruby, but it will downcase the rest of the string. You can write your own otherwise:

```
class String
  def capitalize_first
    (slice(0) || '').upcase + (slice(1..-1) || '')
  end

  def capitalize_first!
    replace(capitalize_first)
  end
end
```

**Edit:** Added `capitalize_first!` variant.

Comment: `capitalize` is from ruby, not rails.

Comment: I think your answer works the best of all, but it is too verbose.

Answer (score 2):

Rather clumsy, but it works:

```
str = "hello IiPad"
str[0] = str[0].upcase #or .capitalize
```

Comment: you have to check for an empty string, running your snippet with `str = ""` will crash.

Comment: Thanks. I now realize that I have to do something that treats the first character separately.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to other answers, I realized some points that I need to be aware of, and also that there is no built in way. I looked into the source of `camelize` in Active Support of Rails as hinted by Vitaly Zemlyansky, which gave me a hint: that is to use a regex. I decided to use this:

```
sub(/./){$&.upcase}
```

Answer (score -3):

Try this

```
"hello iPad".camelize
```

Comment: This will really Camelize the string. What if the provided string contains `some_undesrcores`? It will be camelized to `someUnderscore`.

Comment: Nice trick, but this will turn "hello some_stuff" into "Hello someStuff". If you don't have any underscores, that's ok, but otherwise that might induce some surprising results (and surprises are usually not welcomed)

Comment: Thanks for the idea. Although it has a problem as pointed out by Remus and Jean, looking into the source code of `camelize` gave me a hint.